# What is the best way to make synchronous calls using Angular's HttpClient?

Tags: angular, async-await, observable, synchronous, angular-httpclient

I have an array of objects of the following type.

**processing-details.model.ts**

```
export class ProcessingDetails{
     id: string;
     isProcessingOccured: boolean;
     isProcessingSuccessful:boolean;
     constructor(id,isProcessingOccured,isProcessingSuccessful) {
          this.id = id;
          this.isProcessingOccured = isProcessingOccured;
          this.isProcessingSuccessful = isProcessingSuccessful;
     }
}
```

The array is dynamically generated based on certain inputs. Once the array is generated, it looks as follows.

```
processingArray = [{id:1, isProcessingOccured: false, isProcessingSuccessful: false},
                   {id:2, isProcessingOccured: false, isProcessingSuccessful: false},
                   .....
                   {id:k, isProcessingOccured: false, isProcessingSuccessful: false}]
```

I have a REST end point which takes an object of type ProcessingDetails. The following is my service code.

**automated-batch.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AutomatedBatchService {
     constructor(@Inject('baseUrl') private baseUrl: string, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

     public triggerProcessing(batchDetails:ProcessingDetails) {
         return this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseUrl}`,batchDetails);
     }
}
```

My goal is to call `triggerProcessing` for each element of `processingArray` in a synchronous manner. If  `triggerProcessing` is called on one object of `processingArray` we set `isProcessingOccured` on that particular object as `true`. If the back end returns a success for the `triggerProcessing` call we made on the object, then we set `isProcessingSuccessful` to `true`. For example, let us assume processing was successful for id = 1 and id = 2. The array must look like follows:

```
    processingArray = [{id:1, isProcessingOccured: true, isProcessingSuccessful: true},
                       {id:2, isProcessingOccured: true, isProcessingSuccessful: true},
                       {id: 3, isProcessingOccured: false, isProcessingSuccessful:false }
                       .....
                       {id:k, isProcessingOccured: false, isProcessingSuccessful: false}]
```

If the processing for one object fails, we must not process the remainder of the array. For example, if processing fails for object `{id: 3, isProcessingOccured: false, isProcessingSuccessful:false }`, we must not trigger the service call from `{id: 4, isProcessingOccured: false, isProcessingSuccessful:false }` onwards.

I am currently using `async/await` to achieve this. Following is my code

**processing-test.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
     selector: 'processing-test',
     templateUrl: './processing-test.component.html',
     styleUrls:['./processing-test.component.css'],
     providers: [AutomatedBatchService]
})
export class ProcessingTestComponent {
     constructor(private automatedBatchService: AutomatedBatchService) { }
     public isSuccess:boolean = true;
     public processingArray: Array<ProcessingDetails>= [];
     async startBatchRun() {
         for( var i = 0; i < this.processingArray.length; i++ ) {
              if(this.isSuccess){
                 await this.automatedBatchService.triggerProcessing(this.processingArray[i])
                 .toPromise()
                 .then(res => {
                     this.processingArray[i].isProcessingOccured = true
                     this.processingArray[i].isProcessingSuccessful = true
                 })
                 .catch(rej => {
                     this.isSuccess = false
                     this.processingArray[i].isProcessingOccured = true
                     this.processingArray[i].isProcessingSuccessful = false
                 });

             }else {
                 break;
             }            
         }
     }
}
```

Is this the best way to achieve this? Is there any way where I can completely avoid using `Promises`, `async/await` and achieve the same synchronous call using `Observables`?

Comment: Use `forkJoin` or `switchMap`.

Comment: forkJoin is no use, as that will process them in parallel. OP want to process them serially - one after the other.

Comment: @Arcteezy, `forkJoin` won't help. I am wanting to process serially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of `concat`, `catchError` and `finalize` to process your requests in order and stop as soon as an error occurs:

```
public process(batch: ProcessingDetails[]) {
  const processes = batch.map(details => this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, batchDetails).pipe(
    map(() => {
      details.isProcessingSuccessful = true;
      return batch;
    }),
    catchError(() => {
      details.isProcessingSuccessful = false;
      return throwError(false);
    }),
    finalize(() => {
      details.isProcessingOccured = true;
    }),
  ));
  return concat(...processes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Observables, how about the following solution. It is not perfect, but I would say the requirement (synchronous HTTP calls) is also isn't.

processing-test.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
     selector: 'processing-test',
     templateUrl: './processing-test.component.html',
     styleUrls:['./processing-test.component.css'],
     providers: [AutomatedBatchService]
})
export class ProcessingTestComponent {
  public isSuccess = true;
  public processingArray: Array<ProcessingDetails>= [];
  private processSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private automatedBatchService: AutomatedBatchService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.batchRun();
  }

  private batchRun() {
    let i = 0;
    if (i < this.processingArray.length) {
      this.processSubscription = this.automatedBatchService.triggerProcessing(this.processingArray[i]).subscribe(
        response => {
          this.processingArray[i].isProcessingOccured = true;
          this.processingArray[i].isProcessingSuccessful = true;
          i++;
          this.batchRun();
        },
        error => {
          this.isSuccess = false;
          this.processingArray[i].isProcessingOccured = true;
          this.processingArray[i].isProcessingSuccessful = false;
        }
      );
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.processSubscription) {
      this.processSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

automated-batch.service.ts

```
import { Subject, Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AutomatedBatchService {
  private httpSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(@Inject('baseUrl') private baseUrl: string, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public triggerProcessing(batchDetails:ProcessingDetails) {
    const result = new Subject<number>();

    if (this.httpSubscription) {
      this.httpSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, batchDetails).subscribe(
      response => { result.next(response.status); },
      error => { result.error(error.status); }
    );

    return result.asObservable();
  }

}
```

One advantage of this approach is since we call the function repeatedly for successive elements, we could induce an explicit delay using `setTimeout()` if required. For eg. inside the `batchRun()` function, the call would be `setTimeout(() => { this.batchRun(); }, 2000);`.